# Mongoid: protect attributes from being changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to protect rails model attributes from being changed, only after the model enter certain state (eg. sign_in_count > 1). Looked around and see people using

```
attr_readonly
```

to protect the attributes, can I use it with condition? If not, is there alternative solution? Thanks.

Comment: what rails version are you using ?

Comment: ok you can see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want to do, so here are some general but related purpose. Btw, in `rails 4` the attributes are protected, but you can use `protected_attributes` gem to go through `rails 3` behaviour.

Btw, in `ruby` you can use `freeze` method can be invoked to prevent from any modifications of some object you have frozen. (Toc check wether the object is indeed frozen, you can call `frozen?` on that object and this will return true or false).

Another remark is that you can check some change state of your model by calling `changed—attributes`, this returns a Hash of fields that changed relatively to their original values.

Edit : you can of course set this statement

```
attr_readonly :some, :attributes unless some_condition
```

and define

```
def some_condition
   sign_in_count > 1
end
```